# Tapestry: default value for a dropdown component

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, tapestry

I use the following code for a select-component:

Java-class:

```
@Component(parameters = {"blankOption=AUTO", "model=someModel", "value=someId",
                         "zone=someZone"})
private Select demoSelect;
```

Template:

```
<select t:id="demoSelect" />
```

This gets rendered to something like the following:

```
<select id="demoSelect" name="demoSelect">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2">second</option>
    <option value="3">third</option>
</select>
```

The behavior I'm looking for is, that a certain option is preselected (this should be decided in the page class). How can I configure this in Tapestry? Basically I need to tell Tapestry to render the "selected" for the appropriate option, e.g.:

```
<select id="demoSelect" name="demoSelect">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">second</option>
    <option value="3">third</option>
</select>
```

Does it suffice to alter the model (I don't think so), or do I have to extend the Select-component itself. I have found [this article](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToCreateAPropertyEditBlock), which looked quite promising, but unfortunately all links to the source codes are dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to extend anything. Just setting the property to a value before the rendering does the trick:

```
@Property
private SomeType someId;

@SetupRender
void initSomeId() {
    if (this.someId == null) {
       this.someId = this.getDefaultValueForSomeId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just overlooked this straightforward way.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to fix this if you would like it to automatically default to the first option you can change the `blankOption="AUTO"` to `blankOption="NEVER"`.

This will remove the *sometimes* unnecessary initial blank space (Tapestry feature) of the dropdown. Useful to make it so the user is unable to just leave the selection empty and frees up exception handling.